# SQL Group By subquery in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to group by the foolowing table but I also need to group the column ID as depitected on the image.

[image]

```
SELECT SUM(ml),sku,name FROM consumos 
GROUP BY sku,name
ORDER BY name
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Best regards

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want a JSON array. This can be done using `jsonb_agg()`:

```
select name, sku, ml, jsonb_agg(id)
from the_table
group by name, sku, ml;
```

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, this would look like:

```
select name, sku, ml,
       '[' || listagg(id, ',') within group (order by id) || ']' as ids
from t
group by name, sku, ml
order by name, count(*);
```

However, not all databases support that standard operator `||` for string concatenation.  And not all databases call their string aggregation operator `listagg()`.  So you might need to tweak the query for your database.

EDIT:

In Postgres, this would be:

```
select name, sku, ml,
       '[' || string_agg(id, ',' order by id)  || ']' as ids
from t
group by name, sku, ml
order by name, count(*);
```

Comment: Hi, i am using postgresql. Thanks